# Bootstrap Modal Doesn't dismiss due to code conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using ELA bootstrap admin template.

There is a sidebarmenu.js file included in the theme which is used for sidebar menu  List Open/Close. Every thing works file. But I wanted to implement Bootstrap Modal,  inside my application. On button click, modal pops up but 'x' or close button seems to be not working. Nether it closes on clicking outside the modal area.

When I comment out inclusion of sidebarmenu.js from the header, the modal works fine. 
Here is sidebarmenu.js code:

```js
(function (global, factory) {
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(['jquery'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports !== "undefined") {
    factory(require('jquery'));
  } else {
    var mod = {
      exports: {}
    };
    factory(global.jquery);
    global.metisMenu = mod.exports;
  }
})(this, function (_jquery) {
  'use strict';

  var _jquery2 = _interopRequireDefault(_jquery);

  function _interopRequireDefault(obj) {
    return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : {
      default: obj
    };
  }

  var _typeof = typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol" ? function (obj) {
    return typeof obj;
  } : function (obj) {
    return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj;
  };

  function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
    if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
      throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
    }
  }

  var Util = function ($) {
    var transition = false;

    var TransitionEndEvent = {
      WebkitTransition: 'webkitTransitionEnd',
      MozTransition: 'transitionend',
      OTransition: 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
      transition: 'transitionend'
    };

    function getSpecialTransitionEndEvent() {
      return {
        bindType: transition.end,
        delegateType: transition.end,
        handle: function handle(event) {
          if ($(event.target).is(this)) {
            return event.handleObj.handler.apply(this, arguments);
          }
          return undefined;
        }
      };
    }

    function transitionEndTest() {
      if (window.QUnit) {
        return false;
      }

      var el = document.createElement('mm');

      for (var name in TransitionEndEvent) {
        if (el.style[name] !== undefined) {
          return {
            end: TransitionEndEvent[name]
          };
        }
      }

      return false;
    }

    function transitionEndEmulator(duration) {
      var _this2 = this;

      var called = false;

      $(this).one(Util.TRANSITION_END, function () {
        called = true;
      });

      setTimeout(function () {
        if (!called) {
          Util.triggerTransitionEnd(_this2);
        }
      }, duration);

      return this;
    }

    function setTransitionEndSupport() {
      transition = transitionEndTest();
      $.fn.emulateTransitionEnd = transitionEndEmulator;

      if (Util.supportsTransitionEnd()) {
        $.event.special[Util.TRANSITION_END] = getSpecialTransitionEndEvent();
      }
    }

    var Util = {
      TRANSITION_END: 'mmTransitionEnd',

      triggerTransitionEnd: function triggerTransitionEnd(element) {
        $(element).trigger(transition.end);
      },
      supportsTransitionEnd: function supportsTransitionEnd() {
        return Boolean(transition);
      }
    };

    setTransitionEndSupport();

    return Util;
  }(jQuery);

  var MetisMenu = function ($) {

    var NAME = 'metisMenu';
    var DATA_KEY = 'metisMenu';
    var EVENT_KEY = '.' + DATA_KEY;
    var DATA_API_KEY = '.data-api';
    var JQUERY_NO_CONFLICT = $.fn[NAME];
    var TRANSITION_DURATION = 350;

    var Default = {
      toggle: true,
      preventDefault: true,
      activeClass: 'active',
      collapseClass: 'collapse',
      collapseInClass: 'in',
      collapsingClass: 'collapsing',
      triggerElement: 'a',
      parentTrigger: 'li',
      subMenu: 'ul'
    };

    var Event = {
      SHOW: 'show' + EVENT_KEY,
      SHOWN: 'shown' + EVENT_KEY,
      HIDE: 'hide' + EVENT_KEY,
      HIDDEN: 'hidden' + EVENT_KEY,
      CLICK_DATA_API: 'click' + EVENT_KEY + DATA_API_KEY
    };

    var MetisMenu = function () {
      function MetisMenu(element, config) {
        _classCallCheck(this, MetisMenu);

        this._element = element;
        this._config = this._getConfig(config);
        this._transitioning = null;

        this.init();
      }

      MetisMenu.prototype.init = function init() {
        var self = this;
        $(this._element).find(this._config.parentTrigger + '.' + this._config.activeClass).has(this._config.subMenu).children(this._config.subMenu).attr('aria-expanded', true).addClass(this._config.collapseClass + ' ' + this._config.collapseInClass);

        $(this._element).find(this._config.parentTrigger).not('.' + this._config.activeClass).has(this._config.subMenu).children(this._config.subMenu).attr('aria-expanded', false).addClass(this._config.collapseClass);

        $(this._element).find(this._config.parentTrigger).has(this._config.subMenu).children(this._config.triggerElement).on(Event.CLICK_DATA_API, function (e) {
          var _this = $(this);
          var _parent = _this.parent(self._config.parentTrigger);
          var _siblings = _parent.siblings(self._config.parentTrigger).children(self._config.triggerElement);
          var _list = _parent.children(self._config.subMenu);
          if (self._config.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
          if (_this.attr('aria-disabled') === 'true') {
            return;
          }
          if (_parent.hasClass(self._config.activeClass)) {
            _this.attr('aria-expanded', false);
            self._hide(_list);
          } else {
            self._show(_list);
            _this.attr('aria-expanded', true);
            if (self._config.toggle) {
              _siblings.attr('aria-expanded', false);
            }
          }

          if (self._config.onTransitionStart) {
            self._config.onTransitionStart(e);
          }
        });
      };

      MetisMenu.prototype._show = function _show(element) {
        if (this._transitioning || $(element).hasClass(this._config.collapsingClass)) {
          return;
        }
        var _this = this;
        var _el = $(element);

        var startEvent = $.Event(Event.SHOW);
        _el.trigger(startEvent);

        if (startEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
          return;
        }

        _el.parent(this._config.parentTrigger).addClass(this._config.activeClass);

        if (this._config.toggle) {
          this._hide(_el.parent(this._config.parentTrigger).siblings().children(this._config.subMenu + '.' + this._config.collapseInClass).attr('aria-expanded', false));
        }

        _el.removeClass(this._config.collapseClass).addClass(this._config.collapsingClass).height(0);

        this.setTransitioning(true);

        var complete = function complete() {

          _el.removeClass(_this._config.collapsingClass).addClass(_this._config.collapseClass + ' ' + _this._config.collapseInClass).height('').attr('aria-expanded', true);

          _this.setTransitioning(false);

          _el.trigger(Event.SHOWN);
        };

        if (!Util.supportsTransitionEnd()) {
          complete();
          return;
        }

        _el.height(_el[0].scrollHeight).one(Util.TRANSITION_END, complete).emulateTransitionEnd(TRANSITION_DURATION);
      };

      MetisMenu.prototype._hide = function _hide(element) {

        if (this._transitioning || !$(element).hasClass(this._config.collapseInClass)) {
          return;
        }
        var _this = this;
        var _el = $(element);

        var startEvent = $.Event(Event.HIDE);
        _el.trigger(startEvent);

        if (startEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
          return;
        }

        _el.parent(this._config.parentTrigger).removeClass(this._config.activeClass);
        _el.height(_el.height())[0].offsetHeight;

        _el.addClass(this._config.collapsingClass).removeClass(this._config.collapseClass).removeClass(this._config.collapseInClass);

        this.setTransitioning(true);

        var complete = function complete() {
          if (_this._transitioning && _this._config.onTransitionEnd) {
            _this._config.onTransitionEnd();
          }

          _this.setTransitioning(false);
          _el.trigger(Event.HIDDEN);

          _el.removeClass(_this._config.collapsingClass).addClass(_this._config.collapseClass).attr('aria-expanded', false);
        };

        if (!Util.supportsTransitionEnd()) {
          complete();
          return;
        }

        _el.height() == 0 || _el.css('display') == 'none' ? complete() : _el.height(0).one(Util.TRANSITION_END, complete).emulateTransitionEnd(TRANSITION_DURATION);
      };

      MetisMenu.prototype.setTransitioning = function setTransitioning(isTransitioning) {
        this._transitioning = isTransitioning;
      };

      MetisMenu.prototype.dispose = function dispose() {
        $.removeData(this._element, DATA_KEY);

        $(this._element).find(this._config.parentTrigger).has(this._config.subMenu).children(this._config.triggerElement).off('click');

        this._transitioning = null;
        this._config = null;
        this._element = null;
      };

      MetisMenu.prototype._getConfig = function _getConfig(config) {
        config = $.extend({}, Default, config);
        return config;
      };

      MetisMenu._jQueryInterface = function _jQueryInterface(config) {
        return this.each(function () {
          var $this = $(this);
          var data = $this.data(DATA_KEY);
          var _config = $.extend({}, Default, $this.data(), (typeof config === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : _typeof(config)) === 'object' && config);

          if (!data && /dispose/.test(config)) {
            this.dispose();
          }

          if (!data) {
            data = new MetisMenu(this, _config);
            $this.data(DATA_KEY, data);
          }

          if (typeof config === 'string') {
            if (data[config] === undefined) {
              throw new Error('No method named "' + config + '"');
            }
            data[config]();
          }
        });
      };

      return MetisMenu;
    }();

    /**
     * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * jQuery
     * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    $.fn[NAME] = MetisMenu._jQueryInterface;
    $.fn[NAME].Constructor = MetisMenu;
    $.fn[NAME].noConflict = function () {
      $.fn[NAME] = JQUERY_NO_CONFLICT;
      return MetisMenu._jQueryInterface;
    };
    return MetisMenu;
  }(jQuery);
});
```

I don't know why this code is having conflict with the dismissal of bootstrap modal dialog. Since, I am beginner in JavaScript/JQuery I am unable to find which section of above code is causing problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? If you open the developer console (usually by pressing the F12 key), do you see errors?

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap 4, this probably relevant: https://github.com/onokumus/metismenu/issues/153 - make sure you're using version 2.7.9 or newer of Metis Menu.

Comment: you can use ```$("#idmodal').modal('hide');``` to close modal.